# Norm of composition of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are real Banach spaces (can be assumed finite-dimensional). Consider the Banach space $Z:=X\bigoplus_\infty Y$, where for any member $(x,y)\in Z$, $\|(x,y)\|:=\max\{\|x\|,\|y\|\}$. Let $\pi_1:Z\to X$ be the projection map.

*My question:*

Let $f\in X^*$ and let $g=f\circ\pi_1: Z \to R$. Is it true that $\|g\|=\|f\|$? If not under what condition it will hold true? If yes, then can we also say that given any $f_1,f_2\in X^*$, $\|f_1\circ \pi_1-f_2\circ \pi_1\|=\|f_1-f_2\|$?

I am a beginner in functional analysis. A detailed answer will be very much of help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: YES, to both and the proofs are easy consequences of the definition of the norm on $Z$.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thankyou@KaviRamaMurthy, for your comment. I have just done $|f\circ \pi_1(x_1,x_2)|=|f(x_1) |\leq \|f\|\|x_1\|\leq \|f\|\max \{\|x_1\|,\|x_2\|\}$. Thus, $\|f\circ \pi_1\|\leq \|f\|$. But What about the other side? I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\|x\|=1$ and note that $g(x,0)=f(x)$. Since $\|(x,0)\|=1$ we see that $\|g\| \geq |f(x)|$ take sup over all $x$ with $\|x\|=1$  to get $\|g\| \geq \|f\|$. The last part follows trivially from this by changing $f$ to $f_1-f_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.